# How to install & use sigmajs in angular 8

Tags: angular, sigma.js, graphology

I would like to add sigmajs to angular 8 to draw a network chart (including more than 1000 nodes & edges) with drag-drop. How can I use it? Which version of sigmajs (and graphology) is compatible with angular 8?

My environment: NodeJS 10.24.1 & Angular CLI 8

My sigmajs & graphology version

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "graphology": "^0.11.4",
    "sigma": "^1.2.2",
    ...
}
```

My component

```
import Graph from "graphology";
import sigma from "sigma";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const graph = new Graph();
        graph.import({
            nodes: [
                {key:"0.0",attributes:{x:268,y:91,size:22,label:"Myriel",color:"#D8482D"}},
                {key:"1.0",attributes:{x:296,y:57,size:15,label:"Napoleon",color:"#B30000"}}
            ],
            edges: [
                {key:"0",source:"1.0",target:"0.0",attributes:{size:1}}
            ]
        });
        const renderer = new sigma(graph, document.getElementById("myid"));
        renderer.refresh();
    }
}
```

My code compiled with no error but it doesn't render the chart. What should I do?

Comment: Sigma.js does not depend on Angular.

Comment: @rveerd does it mean I can use the latest version (2.4.0) of sigmajs?
I tried and got typescript compile error (I'm using nodejs 10 and typescript 3.5.3)
Could you please help?

Comment: For others to help you, you need describe what you have tried and what errors you got. Edit your question and add the relevant details.

Comment: Also, the versions you are using are very, very old. You should upgrade to recent versions of Node.js, Angular and TypeScript if that is possible.

Comment: @rveerd I know they are old, but this project isn't my own so I have no permission to upgrade them. I managed to fix the compilation error by changing version of sigma & graphology and provided my code in the question. Could you please take a look?